# CakePHP getting column values

Tags: datetime, cakephp

So I have a login function in my web application. Whenever a user logs in, the application will automatically get the current date and time and save it in the database column name 'current_login'. Okay, this is working. Then once the user logs out, the application will then update the column 'last_login' the same value as the 'current_login' column. So once the user logs in again, their home page will show: 'Your last login was on: ".

This is an example:
User logs in on 01-30-2015 16:30:00 -> 'current_login' column gets the value 01-30-2015 16:30:00
User logs out -> 'last_login' column gets the value of 'current_login'
User logs in on 01-30-2015 17:00:00 -> 'current_login' column gets the value 01-30-2015 17:00:00
User home page shows the message "Your last login was on:" as 01-30-2015 16:30:00

My problem is that I can't seem to update the 'last_login' column. Either it shows null, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, or other weird datetime values.

Here is my code for updating the current_login:

```
public function updateCurrentTime(){
            $this->User->id = $this->Auth->User('usersId');
            $this->User->saveField('current_login', DboSource::expression('NOW()'));
        }
```

The function updateCurrentTime() is working.

I'm not sure how to code the logout() function though, been trying it for almost a day.

```
public function logout() {
        //insert code for 'last_login'
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're not sure the user is calling the logout action. What if he closes the tab? I should work with a `sessions` table, but in your case the best thing to do is move the `current_login` value to the `last_login` value and set the `current_login` to the current time on every login.

Comment: I did. That was what I'm doing. Everytime a user logs out, current_login and last_login have the same value. But once the user logs in again, the current_login updates. Anyway, I think I did it. But not sure how to do the sessions though.